# how to insert image from url in markdown

Tags: r, graphics, markdown

The way to insert an image to markdown file is (and it is outside "`{r}`")

```
<center><src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4NzEyNzQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTY3NDg4._V1._CR24,0,293,443_SX214_AL_.jpg"></center>
```

But I want to make url as a variable. So I tried something like this:

````
```{r, result='asis'}
url <- "http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"
print(paste("<center><src=\"", url, "\"></center>", collapse=""))
```
````

But it doesn't work. The result I get

```
## [1] "<center><src=\" http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4NzEyNzQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTY3NDg4._V1._CR24,0,293,443_SX214_AL_.jpg \"></center>"
```

Is there any chance to make the string of characters like on the top of my question so get rid of `## [1]` and quotes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can do it using inline R code. For example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
# Define variable containing url
url <- "http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"
```
## Some cat!
<center><img src="`r url`"></center>

## Alternatively...
![](`r url`)
````

Comment: Very clever solution. Out of interest, why do some tags work normally, like `<center>`, but others (like `<img ..>` do not?

Comment: Is there a way to resize the images in the first method?

Comment: We can use html properties or css styling to resize the images...

Comment: Brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing Richard's answer to be able to print the image within the code chunk.
You can add this in a code chunk with the following parameters (surrounded with triple back ticks on lines before and after R code chunk):

```
{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
image = "https://cdn.britannica.com/84/206384-050-00698723/Javan-gliding-tree-frog.jpg"
cat(paste0('<center><img src="', image,  '"></center>'))
```